# How do I mock a class inside a module called from another module in Python?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have a structure like this:

```
dir_a/
    foo.py
    bar.py
dir_b/
    parameters.py
```

I am trying to mock the `Parameters` class in `parameters.py` when testing. Both `foo.py` and `bar.py` import and use `Parameters` in the same way. Class `Foo` creates instances of class `Bar`.

My problem is that `Foo` gets the mocked version of `Parameters` but not `Bar`. I (thought I) understand the concept of where to patch, but still it seems like the issue is there. This is the test code:

```py
@mock.patch("path.to.foo.Parameters")
@mock.patch("path.to.bar.Parameters")
def test_something(self, bar_mock, foo_mock):
    foo_mock().get.return_value = 'val1'
    bar_mock().get.return_value = 'val2'
    Foo().load()
```

`load()` creates instances of `Bar`. Within `foo` I have the mocked `Parameters` and within `bar` I have the normal `Parameters`. What am I missing here?
If I directly from the test call `Bar()`, then it gets the mocked version.

And then a follow-up question. How can I mock the return values for different inputs to get? If I add parenthesis after get, like `bar_mock().get('param.a').return_value`, the return value becomes a MagicMock instead of a value.

**Small update**

What I didn't mention is that `Parameters` uses the Borg singleton pattern. It shouldn't matter because when I tried to make a reproducible example, it worked with the Borg pattern. My original problem (why I wanted to mock it from the beginning) was that if I initiate `Parameters` in the test, the production code still has its own (uninitiated) instance.

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @KlausD., I've now been trying to create a minimal reproducible example, but cannot seem to get the same behavior no matter how hard I try to make it look exactly like the real code. Sorry about that! I need to continue to figure out what can be wrong. If I find anything or get a reproducible example, I'll let you know!

Comment: The question lacks the requirement. You have to produce a reproducible code example along with the way `Parameters` are imported inside the class Foo and Bar. Then this will give us an idea to reproduce the code and provide the solution

Comment: @Roxy, both Foo and Bar import it with `from dir_b.parameters import Parameters`. Yeah sorry, I should have tried a reproducible example before posting. In my example the mocking works as expected. So I'm trying to figure out why and where it's going wrong in my code.

Comment: And if I directly call `Bar()` from the test it does get the mocked version..